# Send email confirmation token as clickable link to user upon registration in ASP.NET Core Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, amazon-ses, email-confirmation

I am using AWS SES service to send email to users.
Upon registration, a token is generated in my AccountServive.sc

```
var confirmEmailToken = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
```

I have a function in this service `SendEmailForAccountCreatedAndEmailVerification` which takes the username, and link to replace the HTML body for an email. And this body is passed in the EmailSender function.

How to create link from this token that the user receives in his/her mail which can be clicked to confirm is email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full code for generating activation link already defined under `Register.cshtml.cs` and `RegisterConfirmation.cshtml.cs` :

```cs
var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
EmailConfirmationUrl = Url.Page(
    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
    pageHandler: null,
    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code },
    protocol: Request.Scheme);
```

Comment: I have been trying this and the variations of this. I am consistently getting an error: `The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context`
Similary for Request

Comment: I'm not generating link in the controller base, I'm working in the service class where I want to generate the link. That's why, Url.Action won't work

Comment: So, the `ConfirmEmail` is in a different project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214474/discussion-between-mansi-and-laz-ziya).